# ArgoCD: Reconciliation Timeout Too Small

Tags: git, go, github, kubernetes, argocd

I'm a newbie in ArgoCD and I have a question like below: by default, ArgoCD polls Git repositories every [three minutes](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/webhook/#overview) to detect changes to the manifests. And one way to reduce this delay (according to my Google search [here](https://www.buchatech.com/2022/08/how-to-set-the-application-reconciliation-timeout-in-argo-cd/)) is to change the value of `timeout.reconciliation` , which is defined in the **ConfigMap** `argocd-cm`, to whatever number we want to change it to.

So my question is: what are the drawbacks if our `timeout.reconciliation` value is "small", let's say `10s` for example, please ? Are there any technical problems if we do this, please?

Thank you guys !!!

Comment: If you are looking for a really fast solution, you should look into configuring webhooks. If your repository is really large, and your reconciliation timeout is short, then you may be adding load on Argo where a previous git poll wont finish in that duration

Comment: @LostJon ah yes, you're right, if our repo is too large, we'll put too many load on Argo server. Thank you for the explanation !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need such a low sync timer, on small ArgoCD installations this might be fine, but if ArgoCD is managing lot's of applications this might consume too many resources.

That being said, if you want to "push" instead of wait for Argo to "pull" you could configure Git Webhooks: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/webhook/

Or you can also work with curl commands:

```
token=<jwt-token>
curl -k -X POST https://<ARGO-URL>/api/v1/applications/<application>/sync --cookie "argocd.token=${token}" --data '{"revision":"master","prune":false,"dryRun":false,"strategy":{},"resources":null}'
```